# X-Frame-Options not set in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, x-frame-options

I am using the following code in my `doGet()` to prevent `X-Frame-Options` from being `sameorigin` but it does not affect the headers in the final script.

```js
function doGet(e) {
  page_titles = {
    "Setup": "title1",
    //....
  }
  if (!e.parameter.page) {
    // When no specific page requested, return "home page"
    var homepage = "Setup";
    var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(homepage).evaluate();
    html.setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
    html.setTitle(titles[homepage]);
    return html;
  }
  //...
}
```

[image: X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking bugs/issues in the [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:191640), found [this comment](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/77281296#comment2) (for the exact same issue)

The explanation:
URL to the script must end in `/exec` and not `/dev`.